# How to create a test case for a job instead of a single component in Talend

Tags: testing, etl, talend

Is it possible to create a test case for a specific job instead of only a component in it?

This is useful sometimes when you want to create some automation tests for the job level but the component level.
Seems now we can only create test case for a component of a job, and when I try to create a standard job and use it as a test case, I don't know how to integrate it into the CI/CD automation test process because it can't be recognized as a test by the Talend tools chain.

Any suggestion about how should I implement the job level tests?

Thanks!

Comment: I know that in the commercial version there are joblets which can be used for job testing: https://help.talend.com/reader/83guyAh0rzDRBiN3NHvhGA/nyCFXAQTTDEuQ2hiCz28mg (Talend - What is a Joblet) Haven't used them for that, though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My suggestion is to build your job that you want to test as jar file, lets say its called `alpha_job`, then create a new job called `test_bench` that prepare the input for `alpha_job`, launch it and perform some test on output.

This may be costly, but it you have a very complicated job, its a good choice, and always try to make the `test_bench` exterimely simple so you dont need to test the `test_bench` itself.

If you have a simple job to test, we usaually test it manually or by MsExcel.